# declaring empty array variable inside method

Tags: javascript

I am creating class to use getUserMedia. Inside method `startRecording()` I am trying to declare/redeclare an empty array `this.recordedBlobs = [];` which should hold recorded data from media stream.
The data is supposed to be added on `this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` event, by calling method `this.handleDataAvailable`. But `this.handleDataAvailable` keeps throwing error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: recordedBlobs is not defined
at MediaRecorder.handleDataAvailable
```

The whole part of class look like this:

```
startRecording() {
    this.snapshotButton.disabled = true;
    this.sendButton.disabled = true;
    this.stopButton.disabled = false;
    this.recordButton.textContent = 'Pause';

    this.recordedBlobs = [];
    let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
    if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
        console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
        options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
        if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
            console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
            options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
                console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
                options = {mimeType: ''};
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Created MediaRecorder', this.mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
        console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
    };
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.handleDataAvailable;
    this.mediaRecorder.start(10); // collect 10ms of data
    console.log('MediaRecorder started', this.mediaRecorder);
    return this.recordedBlobs;
}
stopRecording() {
    this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    this.recordButton.textContent = 'Start';
    this.snapshotButton.disabled = false;
    this.sendButton.disabled = false;
    this.sendButton.textContent = 'Send Video';
    this.stopButton.disabled = true;
    console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', this.recordedBlobs);
}
handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        this.recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why `handleDataAvailable` can not access `this.recordedBlobs`.
Any help greatly appreciated.

This is the constructor:

```
constructor(button, constraints) {
    this.constraints = constraints;
    this.openVideoPanelButton = document.querySelector(button);
    this.openVideoPanelButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        this.openVideoPanel();
    });
    console.log('initialized');
}
```

It is not really duplicate because inside `handleDataAvailable()` method I am able to access `this` but the value of `this` contains only MediaRecorder object

Comment: Have you bound `handleDataAvailable` in constructor?

Comment: Please provide the whole class.

Comment: how to add handleDataAvailable into constructor? as a variable pointing to method?

Comment: here is the whole class so far https://jsfiddle.net/igor77/zkqg27eh/5/

Comment: This is a duplicate. Read it again, and try the suggestions in the answer. I think you'll find using `bind` to work well.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor method try to initialize with empty Array

```
constructor(){
    this.recordedBlobs = [];
}
```

Comment: when added to constructor now i am getting different error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at MediaRecorder.handleDataAvailable